# A JS component for HTML discussions a-la Google Docs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, components

I'm looking for a JavaScript component that would support discussions for my *read-only* HTML documents, a-la what modern Google Documents do.

User selects a random portion of web-page, presses a hotkey / button on the page, and a comment floating pane appears. Portions of web-page that have comments are highlighted in some way unless user disabled that somewhere.

Should support or me allow to easily implement:

- Several users (I provide information on the current user).
- Sane API for server-side, so I can implement it and not take whatever PHP stuff is bundled (even better if it would be abstracted away on JS code level).
- "Resolved" function (actually, it would do if I'll be able to put any custom button)
- Change / delete functions
- Comment stream pane

Answer (score 3):

You're after a web annotation toolkit then. The research world is full of these (which doesn't necessarily mean that they're intended for production use).

Perhaps this one would work? [OKF Annotator](http://okfn.org/projects/annotator/) ([Blog post](http://blog.okfn.org/2010/11/12/open-source-annotation-toolkit-for-inline-online-web-annotation/))

Looks like it powers this: http://annotateit.org/